# duplicate information in the organization in the repeating loop

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to bring the information from the database and organize one to the left and the other to the right, but the information is coming in duplicate

`

```
                <?php if ($i === 0) { ?>
    
        <tr>
          <td align="center" width="100%" style="background-color:#eceded">
            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="<?php echo $D->LINK ?>" target="_blank">
              <img src="<?php echo $D->IMAGEM ?>" alt="" style="width: 207px;border-radius: 15px 0px                                                0px 15px;float: left;margin-left: 71px;">
              <div style="background-color: #ffffff;width: 50%;color: #6a6a6a;border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;margin-left: 219px;height: 209px;">
                <p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;line-height:130%;color:#6a6a6a;text-align:center;padding-top: 0.5em;">
                  <strong><?php echo $D->TITULO ?></strong>
                </p>
                <p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px 35px 0px 35px;"><?php echo $D->DESCRICAO ?></p>
                <img src="https://unifeso.edu.br/email-news/images/btn_news.png" alt="" style="width:                                                                                                                        190px; margin-top: px; margin-left: 7px;">
              </div>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="height:40px;background-color:#eceded">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } else { ?>


            <tr>
              <td align="center" width="100%" style="background-color:#eceded">
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="<?php echo $D->LINK ?>" target="_blank">
                  <img src="<?php echo $D->IMAGEM ?>" alt="" style="width: 207px;border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;float: right;margin-right: 73px;">
                  <div style="background-color: #ffffff;width: 50%;color: #6a6a6a;border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;margin-right: 222px;height: 209px;">
                    <p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;line-height:130%;color:#6a6a6a;text-align:center;padding-top: 0.5em;">
                      <strong><?php echo $D->TITULO ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p style="text-align: right; padding: 0px 35px 0px 35px;"><?php echo $D->DESCRICAO ?></p>
                    <img src="https://unifeso.edu.br/email-news/images/btn_news.png" alt="" style="width: 190px; margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 7px;">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="height:40px;background-color:#eceded">&nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr>
         
            <?php } ?> 
           
        
            
            <tr>
              <td align="center" width="100%" style="background-color:#eceded">
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="<?php echo $D->LINK ?>" target="_blank">
                  <img src="<?php echo $D->IMAGEM ?>" alt="" style="width: 207px;border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;float: left;margin-left: 71px;">
                  <div style="background-color: #ffffff;width: 50%;color: #6a6a6a;border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;margin-left: 219px;height: 209px;">
                    <p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;line-height:130%;color:#6a6a6a;text-align:center;padding-top: 0.5em;">
                      <strong><?php echo $D->TITULO ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px 35px 0px 35px;"><?php echo $D->DESCRICAO ?></p>
                    <img src="https://unifeso.edu.br/email-news/images/btn_news.png" alt="" style="width: 190px; margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 7px;">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="height:40px;background-color:#eceded">&nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr>
```

`

When trying to organize one to the right and the other to the left, it is giving duplicates, the same information is being left and right

Comment: What code inb4 `<?php if ($i === 0) { ?>` ?

Comment: All those inline styles you are using there, should not be inline to begin with. This should be done using the stylesheet in the first place, and not by producing a different output structure. The `:nth-child` selector exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- BODY  -->
```

```
<?php if ($i === 1) { ?>
  <!-- NEWS 0 -->
  content
  <!-- END NEWS 0 -->
<?php } else { ?>

  <?php if ($i == $TOTAL_REG) { ?>

    <?php
    //IF PAIR
    if ($TOTAL_REG % 2 == 0) { ?>

      <!-- FINAL NOTICE RIGHT -->

      content

      <!-- END RIGHT NEWS -->

    <?php } else { //IF ODD ?>

      <!-- FINAL NEWS LEFT -->
      content
      <!-- END NEWS LEFT -->

    <?php } ?>

  <?php } else { ?>

    <!-- BODY OF THE MESSAGE -->
    <?php //IF PAIR
     if ($i % 2 == 0) { ?>

      <!-- NEWS IMAGE RIGHT -->
      content
      <!-- END NEWS 2 -->

    <?php } else { //IF ODD ?>

      <!-- NEWS IMAGE LEFT -->
      content
      <!-- END NEWS  1 -->
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).